# Text overlapping in my sidebar

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am experiencing a weird glitch, i see text overlap in my sidebar. Image attached [overlapping text image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSdbm.jpg)

I am not sure how this happens and i have been trying to figure it out. The overlap is not present when i hover over the item. Here is my html for the sidebar

```
<!-- Sidebar Menu -->
<div ng-controller="SidebarController">
 <ul class="nav sidebar-menu" ng-repeat="comp in competition track by $index" id="rcs-menu-item">
    <li ui-sref-active="active" >
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="{{comp.competitionID}}" ng-click="getTeams(comp.competitionID, comp.Name, comp.calenderID, comp.customName)">
            <i class="menu-icon fa fa-soccer-ball-o"></i>
            <span class="menu-text">{{comp.Name}}</span>
        </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- /Sidebar Menu -->
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can we see your stylesheet?

Comment: Seems like that's the text of the first entry, which is broken into the second line ("South America). We'd need the CSS to find out what's wrong  - seems like a fixed height for the individual entries / `li` tags

Comment: My guess in you're using a fixed height with a line height that matches and the text is wrapping to the next line.

Comment: Wow thanks so much, i have a fixed width sidebar, the name overflow is causing the rest of the text to show up there. Was on this for such a long time Thanks!!

Comment: @johannes sure thing i did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like that's the text of the first entry, which is broken into the second line ("South America).

We'd need the CSS to find out what's wrong - probably a fixed height for the individual entries / `li` tags